# Get rendering parameters when multiple sublayouts of the same type are on the page

Tags: c#, .net, sitecore, sitecore6

I need to get the rendering parameters programmatically from my sublayout. Currently I do this as such:

```
var sublayout = ((Sublayout)this.Parent);
//Get all rendering
var renderings = Sitecore.Context.Item.Visualization.GetRenderings(Sitecore.Context.Device, true);

//Get the first rendering that matches the current sublayout's path
var sublayoutRendering = renderings.FirstOrDefault(r => r.RenderingItem.InnerItem["Path"] == sublayout.Path);

if (sublayoutRendering != null)
    Response.Write(sublayoutRendering.RenderingItem.Parameters);
```

This solution came from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949214/sitecore-how-to-use-sublayout-parameters-from-codebehind) and works perfectly until I have two sublayouts of the same type on the page. When this occurs obviously `renderings.FirstOrDefault(r => r.RenderingItem.InnerItem["Path"] == sublayout.Path);` always returns the first rendering parameter that matches the sublayouts path for *both* sublayouts.

How can I differentiate between them? I can see nothing that I can use to tie them together!

---

**Edit:**

To be clear, I add my sublayout in *Presentation > Details*, then when I click my control I set the fields in the '*Control Properties*' window. I have a field called Module Source which always comes back the same - it always populates as the one highest up in the order. The values are definitely different for each sublayout but I cannot get them from the renderings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I'm missing something. But you can get the sublayouts rendering parameters, directly on the Sublayout. I use the following on my base Sublayout I use for all my Sitecore sublayouts - and it has no problems with rendering parameters on the same sublayout inserted multiple times :)

```
    protected Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Sublayout CurrentSublayout
    {
        get
        {
            Control c = Parent;
            while (c != null && !(c is Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Sublayout))
            {
                c = c.Parent;
                if (c == null)
                    break;
            }

            return c as Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Sublayout;
        }
    }

    protected NameValueCollection CurrentParameters
    {
        get
        {
            if (CurrentSublayout == null)
                return null;

            NameValueCollection parms = WebUtil.ParseUrlParameters(CurrentSublayout.Parameters);

            var sanitizedValues = new NameValueCollection();
            for (int i = 0; i < parms.Count; i++)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(parms[i]))
                    sanitizedValues.Add(parms.Keys[i], parms[i]);
            }

            return sanitizedValues;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This still only gets the parameters from the first item of the same type. When you say you added it to your SubLayout base what do you mean? I have this setup in a function I call - would that make a difference?

Comment: All my Sitecore sublayouts inherits from my own Sublayout class, were I've added some basic functions I often seem to need. I have done test's on this on Sitecore versions 6.1-6.5 with multiple instances of the same sublayout on a single page.

I use a rendering parameter template on my sublayout to control my parameters. But other than that i fail to see were the problem might be. Do you make your parameter check on the specific sublayouts codebehind?

Comment: No, we've got a function that takes a user control and we load the SubLayout by looking at the parent, similar to your `CurrentSublayout
` property. Where do you change what the Sitecore sublayout inherits from?

Comment: okay, we might be on the the problem here :) I create a Sitecore sublayout "MyControl.ascx" in the codebehind "MyControl.ascx.cs" I add my parameter functions. The "cs" file inherits from "System.Web.UI.UserControl" but this I override with my own, this is not necessary for it to work. The main thing here is that the function that work with the parameters is on the "MyControl" codebehind file. If you are trying to cycle trough all the renderings on a single page, then just instead of what you are doing now - just make a for-each loop with your renderings

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the cache settings on your sub-layout, if you don't have Cacheable VarbyParam it is not going to work for you