# How to get sublayout parameters of a parent item or any other Items in Sitecore

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore, sitecore7

I have done some research but did not end up finding a possible solution. 
Here are the topics that I was able to find:

- [Sitecore: How to use sublayout parameters from codebehind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949214/sitecore-how-to-use-sublayout-parameters-from-codebehind)
- https://markstiles.net/Blog/2011/04/27/sitecore-sublayout-parameters-and-datasources.aspx

All are suggesting that this...

```cs
var sublayout = ((Sublayout)this.Parent);
NameValueCollection nvc = Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.ParseUrlParameters(sublayout.Parameters);
```

...is correct but I want more than this, because this method can only give me the current context sub layout, i.e the current page in Sitecore that I was in. I want code that can retrieve the sub layout parameters of a specific item. For example, if I am getting an Item (a page) using a Path, how then can I get its sub layout parameters?

PS: I am using Sitecore 7.0

Comment: Sublayout rendering parameters are configurable for sublayout instances only. You cannot set them for items in the tree. Could you describe more precisely what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I have a tree of items in which some of them could have or maybe don't have the required parameters (let say a check-box for example). A -> B -> C -> D , if i am at page D, I want to iterate up to the parent node until i can find the check-box is checked...

Comment: So you don't want to check rendering parameters of sublayouts. You want to find the first ancestor with the field set on it?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that *you cannot get the sublayout parameters for another sublayout* on the page.

This is because the parameters are not passed until a request is made to that sublayout and the Parameters are added to the request in the pipeline (if I remember correctly, the parameters are passed in the pipeline and not the context - regardless, this will hold true for both).

As such, the only ways to get parameters for a different sublayout are: 
1. If you are in the parent sublayout and are looking at the parameters *that you set yourself in the code* on a child sublayout control 
2. If you went through some overly tedious code (that does something you could much more easily do another way) to go into Sitecore, grab all of the Sublayouts added to the page in Presentation Details, and looked at the parameters for each. However, note that this solution gives you *only parameters that have been set in Sitecore*.

*Neither solution will give you parameters set in the code-behind of another sublayout*.

The second solution is not a good solution, as it will be messy and overly complex. What you should be doing, if you really need to share parameter data like this, is either extending the Sitecore Context (which is probably still more work for what you are doing than is needed), or using Session to share the data (which is probably the best solution for you, but make sure you do not over-use it; as with anything, research [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178581(v=vs.100).aspx) before you start to use it).

**EDIT**

If you are looking for further information on parameters passing in a request you will need to decompile Sitecore.Kernel.DLL and investigate manually. There is no documentation for this, save for maybe a gem or two hidden in blog posts somewhere out there.

In regards to your comment about writing "a function to invoke a request and retrieve a parameter," I would *highly* advise against this. This is a very ugly solution that could easily be replaced by a better one, were we to fully understand your use case.

**Edit 2**

In your comment, you said:

> I have a tree of items in which some of them could have or maybe don't
>   have the required parameters (let say a check-box for example). A -> B
>   -> C -> D , if i am at page D, I want to iterate up to the parent node until i can find the check-box is checked.

From this comment, I believe that you are incorrectly using the word "parameters" in the place of "fields". A Field is a control that has been added to a template (such as a Signle-Line Text field, Rich-Text Field, Checkbox Field, Multilist Field, etc.), given a title on the template, and can be set by a user. Contrarily, a Parameter is a key-value pair passed to a sublayout in the same syntax as a query string. Parameters are set in presentation details, whereas Fields are set on the item itself (or on its __Standard Values or inherited __Standard Values).

If I am correct and you are misusing the word "Parameters" then you do not want to do what you are describing at all. All you will want to do is the following:

```
// looking for the youngest item from the context item through its ancestors that has the "Foo" check box checked

var youngestItemWithFoo = Sitecore.Context.Item; //give the found item a name
bool foundYoungestChecked; //will be our loop condition/flag to show we found the youngest that has the box checked

// we need the root path to ensure that we do not go too far up the tree
var rootPath = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetSite("website").RootPath;

// Foo is a checkbox field - the below checks raw values to see if foo is checked.
// ** Note that the way that this condition is written, the root item (often the "Home" item)
//    will still be checked but the loop will not traverse farther up the tree. You may need
//    to change this to stop the traversal sooner, depending on your solution **

while (!(foundYoungestChecked = youngestItemWithFoo["Foo"] == "1") && youngestItemWithFoo.Paths.Path != rootPath) 
{
    youngestItemWithFoo = youngestItemWithFoo.Parent; // if the Foo field is not checked, look at the parent and continue
}

//make sure that an item was found, as it is possible that none were
if (foundYoungestChecked) 
{
    //...item was found - do your stuff...
} 
else 
{
   //...item was not found - do some other stuff...
}
```

Comment: Hi Zachary, where can I get more information about the parameters passing on a request or not ? I found it doesn't make sense when we can only get the current sublayout parameters but not the parent's sublayout parameter.
Anyway, If what you are saying is true, then can I try to write a function to invoke  a request and retrieve the parameter ???

Comment: Please view the edit under my question. I don't need to share data.

Comment: Yes, you *could* do that - but I would strongly advise against it. The fact that you cannot retrieve a parent sublayout's rendering parameters actually makes perfect sense, as it is purely request based and parameters are really meant for sublayout specific settings that relate to actual presentation, not even to the Item itself. Yes, you can use them for other things, but that is what fields are meant for. If you are looking for further information, see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar for finding a rendering on a parent item in the past. It involved a lot of code wrapping around LayoutDefinition and RenderingDefinition classes. The essential path was to get the layout definition, then get a device, then get the device's renderings. Something like this:

```
Sitecore.Layouts.LayoutDefinition layout = Sitecore.Layouts.LayoutDefinition.Parse(item[Sitecore.FieldIDs.LayoutField]); 
var defaultDeviceId = "{FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3}";

var device = layoutDefinition.GetDevice(defaultDeviceId);
var renderingDefinitions = device.GetRenderings(renderingId);
foreach(var renderingDefinition in renderingDefinitions){
   string parameters = renderingDefinition.Parameters;
}
```

I've assumed an item and the sublayout's ID (renderingId) are available to you. Note also that I have a hard-coded device ID for the Default device in place here for the sample. You may need to loop over multiple devices, or have a configuration item configured for a specific device. Take a look at John West's blog on [updating layout details](https://www.sitecore.net/Learn/Blogs/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2011/09/Programmatically-Update-Layout-Details-with-the-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS.aspx) for an example of how you can get access to this data.

Comment: How can I get the DeviceId or knowing which deice that I am using? Is it alternating depending on the user device ? This device is kind of new to me

Comment: Okay I tried your way but when I call string parameters = renderingDefinition.Parameters; it only return to me the parameter name and default value. Not the value that I configure for my item :'(

Comment: Hi @Nexus, the device you are using can be retrieved with Sitecore.Context.Device, or if you want to specify a specific device you can find them in Sitecore and locate the Item ID or path that you want to load.

As for the parameters, I apologize that it does not load the author-specified values. One way to work around this is to change your sublayout to use a datasource and use renderingDefinition.Datasource to get the data.

Comment: @JayS - Look at Nexus' second comment on his post. I do not think he is looking for parameters at all. I think he confused the word "parameter" with the word "field" in his OP.