# Sitecore 8: Hiding a section or a field in an item

Tags: sitecore, code-behind, sitecore7, sitecore8, content-editor

I have a certain item which uses a sublayout **sub1**. The item created with this sublayout has a field "Switch Columns" which i want to remove or hide (or hide/remove the section "Columned Grid" if possible) . Note that i do not want every item of that **template** to hide the field; just the items using **sub1** (since the template is being used by different sublayouts).

[image]

Is there a way to do this via code in the ascx file of the sublayout ?

Answer (score 3):

You can solve by using an extra layer inherit.

Create 2 set of template fields:
Template field minimal set
Template fields with addition fields.

sub1 Inheritance from the Template field minimal set
other layouts use a template with Inheritance from the minimal set and the addition field.

maybe this is also usable:
For Hide in the Content editor.
You can deny "Field Read" for a role/user on your Template Field or Section item.

See https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/8/t/2113

Comment: I guess I do not understand the question. Answer changed I think you can use Inheritance to solve your issue.

Comment: By inheritence you mean Template Inheritence? which would mean creating another template which inherits from base and make changes to the new template ? As I said earlier, I dont want to make any changes to templates as that would change many existing items.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide fields in the Content Editor with a custom processor in the `getContentEditorFields`, see this post:

http://ctor.io/hide-fields-in-the-sitecore-content-editor/

But as other answers suggested, I would overthink your approach. Personally I would either use two separate Sublayouts (with different number of columns where you can easily swap them later without loosing it's datsource) or use this as a rendering parameter.

Comment: I have used different layouts...as i think using rendering param approach would have no effect on existing items...

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible.  When viewing an item in content editor, your sublayout is not loaded.  I would recommend that you rethink your architecture.  This sort of field should probably be a rendering parameter.  Alternatively, you could create a separate template to act as the data source for those sublayouts.

Comment: That was [already suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34060128/sitecore-8-get-sublayout-item-when-ascx-file-is-shared) to the OP.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe a custom pipeline for the content editor? If you tap into the `<renderContentEditor>` pipeline, you may be able to inspect the item's presentation, sniff out the sublayout, and inject some JavaScript to hide the panel.